# Maven Configuration Issue : Failed to find plugin prefix deploy

Tags: maven, nexus

I am trying to setup Maven(3.2.5) on linux with nexus repo for non Java artifacts. I was going through all the SO questions, and got to know that with Maven command line, one can publish artifacts to repo without POM for non java artifacts.

When I am running maven deploy file command to push non java artifacts(zip file) to nexus repo, and it throws the following error
"Failed to find plugin prefix deploy". I

Here is the pluginGroup tag from my settings.xml, which is under conf dir. How do I get rid of this failed to find plugin error.

Thanks for your time!

```
<pluginGroups>
<pluginGroup>org.apache.maven.plugins</pluginGroup>
</pluginGroups>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This plugin group tag is not required in setting.xml file. I was not able to download plugin from maven due to firewall issue.

after setting up proxy, I was able to use maven build successfully.